# EXCEL workbook - How to put on a website

Tags: website, microsoft-excel

I am using EXCEL from Office 2003. I want to know how I can put a workbook on to a website I have in such a way that a user can simply download it to his machine and then use it. The workbook has some macros in it.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file to Google Docs.   Get the link from Docs.   Put the link on your website with appropriate anchor text or image .